# Find the logical parent pid of a container

Tags: c, linux, docker, linux-kernel, containers

**TL; DR : I'd like to know without relying too much on the underlying containerization engine which process spawned a container when a new container is started**

With recent containerization tools, the main process of a container is generally not the descendant of the process that spawned it. This is because containers are ran daemonized. For exemple with docker, if docker runs a detached container, its ancestors will be `containerd-shim`, `containerd` and `systemd/init(1)` but *not* the shell that spawned it!

Is there a kernel-level way when a container is created to tell which is logical parent, i.e. the process that created it? I’d like to do something like the following pseudocode:

```c
int on_container_spawn(int container_rootpid) {
    int logical_parent = find_logical_parent(container_pid, ...) 
    pr_debug("logical parent of %d is %d", logical_parent, container_rootpid);
    return  logical_parent;
}
```

Although I didn’t try yet, it seems that for OCI-based containers, the `prestart` hook must be a good place to look at but this works only for OCI-based containers and won’t for example work for LXC containers.

Is there a way to get this information without relying too much on the underlying technology? If it’s not feasible do you know how can I do it for a specific technology?

---

Note: I am perfectly aware that the process that spawned the container can be terminated before the container but it doesn’t matter for my use case.